# Python 3.7.1 (Ipython 7.2) console does not start in Pycharm Community 2018.3

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, miniconda

Please, could you help? I am unable to get the python console started in PyCharm. I am using a Win10 machine with miniconda. I have trawled the documentation but cannot figure this one out. Any help would be appreciated. Please find below the error I click on the 'Python Console' tab:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharmCE\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 5, in <module>
    from _pydev_comm.rpc import make_rpc_client, start_rpc_server, start_rpc_server_and_make_client
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharmCE\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\rpc.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _pydev_comm.server import TSingleThreadedServer
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharmCE\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\server.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _shaded_thriftpy.server import TServer
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharmCE\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\server.py", line 9, in <module>
    from _shaded_thriftpy.transport import (
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharmCE\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\transport\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .sslsocket import TSSLSocket, TSSLServerSocket  # noqa
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharmCE\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\transport\sslsocket.py", line 7, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "C:\miniconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Fixed in 2019.1: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured this one out. Anaconda prompt basically changes the PATH variable to include the path where miniconda is installed. Starting Pycharm by itself does not do this. Console works fine after starting anaconda prompt. Hence this is a PATH issue. I found the path variable from the native interpreter after starting Anaconda and copied and pasted the PATH into Console options in Pycharm... and it works like a charm!